# SQL query for counting records per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a dataset I need to build for number of visits per month for particular user. I have a SQL table which contains these fields:

- **User** nvarchar(30)
- **DateVisit** datetime

What I want to achieve now is to get all the visits grouped by month for each user, something like at the picture:

[image]

I started the query, I am able to get the months and the total sum of visits for that month (not split by user) with this query;

```
select  [1] AS January,
  [2] AS February,
  [3] AS March,
  [4] AS April,
  [5] AS May,
  [6] AS June,
  [7] AS July,
  [8] AS August,
  [9] AS September,
  [10] AS October,
  [11] AS November, 
  [12] AS December 
from
(
SELECT MONTH(DateVisit) AS month, [User] FROM UserVisit
) AS t
PIVOT (
COUNT([User])
  FOR month IN([1], [2], [3], [4], [5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) p
```

With the query above I am getting this result:

[image]

Now I want to know how I can add one more column for user and split the values by user.

Comment: Aside: Will the table be limited to user visits from a single year, do you want all years combined, or do you want to filter by year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, both solutions look good.  The answer by Ali works but I would use a SUM() function instead, I hate NULLS.  Let's try both and see the query plans versus execution times.

I always create a test table with data so that I do not give the user, Aziale, bad answers.

The code below is not the prettiest but it does set up a test case.  I made a database in tempdb called user_visits.  For each month, I used a for loop to add the users and give them the create start date for the month.

Now that we have data, we can play.

```
-- Drop the table
drop table tempdb.dbo.user_visits
go

-- Create the table
create table tempdb.dbo.user_visits
(
    uv_id int identity(1, 1),
    uv_visit_date smalldatetime,
    uv_user_name varchar(30)
);
go

-- January data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 103
begin
    if (@cnt <= 21) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130101', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 44) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130101', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 65) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130101', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 103) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130101', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- February data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 99
begin
    if (@cnt <= 29) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130201', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 42) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130201', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 55) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130201', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 99) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130201', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- March data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 98
begin
    if (@cnt <= 25) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130301', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 46) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130301', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 75) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130301', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 98) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130301', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- April data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 91
begin
    if (@cnt <= 32) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130401', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 48) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130401', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 60) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130401', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 91) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130401', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- May data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 120
begin
    if (@cnt <= 40) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130501', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 41) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130501', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 70) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130501', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 120) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130501', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- June data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 103
begin
    if (@cnt <= 17) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130601', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 45) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130601', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 62) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130601', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 103) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130601', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- July data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 99
begin
    if (@cnt <= 20) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130701', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 43) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130701', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 66) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130701', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 99) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130701', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- August data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 98
begin
    if (@cnt <= 26) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130801', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 47) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130801', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 71) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130801', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 98) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130801', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- September data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 91
begin
    if (@cnt <= 25) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130901', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 49) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130901', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 59) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130901', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 91) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20130901', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- October data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 120
begin
    if (@cnt <= 25) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131001', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 40) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131001', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 73) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131001', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 120) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131001', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- November data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 101
begin
    if (@cnt <= 32) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131101', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 50) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131101', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 65) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131101', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 101) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131101', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go

-- December data
declare @cnt int = 1;
while @cnt <= 90
begin
    if (@cnt <= 40) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131201', 'Patrick');

    if (@cnt <= 52) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131201', 'Barbara');

    if (@cnt <= 61) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131201', 'Danielle');

    if (@cnt <= 90) 
        insert into tempdb.dbo.user_visits 
        (uv_visit_date, uv_user_name)
        values ('20131201', 'John');

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
go
```

Please do not use reserve words in coding as column names - IE - month is a reserve word.

The code below gives you the correct answer.

```
-- Grab the data (1)
select 
  my_user, 
  [1] AS January,
  [2] AS Febrary,
  [3] AS March,
  [4] AS April,
  [5] AS May,
  [6] AS June,
  [7] AS July,
  [8] AS August,
  [9] AS September,
  [10] AS October,
  [11] AS November, 
  [12] AS December 
from
(
  SELECT MONTH(uv_visit_date) AS my_month, uv_user_name as my_user FROM tempdb.dbo.user_visits
) AS t
PIVOT (
  COUNT(my_month)
  FOR my_month IN([1], [2], [3], [4], [5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) as p
```

[image]

```
-- Grab the data (2)
SELECT  uv_user_name
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) January
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Feburary
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) March
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) April
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) May
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) June
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) July
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) August
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) September
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) October
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) November
       , SUM(CASE WHEN  MONTH(uv_visit_date) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) December
FROM tempdb.dbo.user_visits
GROUP BY uv_user_name
```

When doing this type of analysis, always clear the cache/buffers and get the I/O.

```
-- Show time & i/o
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO

-- Remove clean buffers & clear plan cache
CHECKPOINT 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO


-- Solution 1
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 42 ms.

(4 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'user_visits'. Scan count 1, logical reads 11, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 5 ms.
```

[image]

```
-- Solution 2
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(4 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'user_visits'. Scan count 1, logical reads 11, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 5 ms.
```

[image]

Both solutions have the same number of reads, work table, etc.  However, the SUM() solution has one less operator.

I am going to give both people who answered a thumbs up +1!!

Comment: +1 for the detailed analysis I was actually wondering which method was better performance wise, cheers buddy , I really like the way you answer questions with details and explanations , keep it up :)

Answer (score 6):

You were nearly there: Just add the user to the select list:

```
select [Usr],
  [1] AS January,
  [2] AS February,
  [3] AS March,
  [4] AS April,
  [5] AS May,
  [6] AS June,
  [7] AS July,
  [8] AS August,
  [9] AS September,
  [10] AS October,
  [11] AS November, 
  [12] AS December 
from
(
SELECT MONTH(DateVisit) AS month, [User], [User] as [Usr] FROM UserVisit
) AS t
PIVOT (
COUNT([User])
  FOR month IN([1], [2], [3], [4], [5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) p
```

Comment: Also, The multi-part identifier "User" could not be bound. one more error

Comment: The multi-part identifier "User" could not be bound, I'm getting that error at line 1

Comment: @Laziale I edited my answer: `User` seems to be a SQL server key word, hence it needs to be quoted using square brackets. And maybe `count(*)` is not supported by `PIVOT`, so I went back to `count([user])` which should be ok, it counts the number of rows where `user` is not null.

Comment: thx for the update @FrankPI, with that update only the error reported at line 1 exists now, with [Type] not getting recognized. Error Message: "Invalid column name 'Type'."

Comment: @Laziale I do not find any `Type` in the whole statement.

Comment: I am sorry [User], line 1 field

Comment: @Laziale Sorry, it seems that using `[User]` in the `Count` makes it unavailable in the result list. I added a second copy with alias `Usr`. Another possibility would be to keep the User unused in the `PIVOT` aggregation by applying `count` to another column of `UserVisit`, maybe the primary key column.

Comment: @FrankPI nope same error even with [Usr] is not recognized, maybe some 'group by' we need to use?

Comment: @Laziale A query similar to my final one works fine for me on SQL 2008R2. Apart from the idea described in my comment above (counting over the primary key column, which needs this to be included in the select list of `t`), I do not have anything further to try. And I need to leave now. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  [User]
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) January
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Feburary
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) March
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) April
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) May
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) June
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) July
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) August
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) September
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) October
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) November
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DateVisit) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) December
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY [USER]
```