# Count the amount of accounts that were closed or null per each month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the total count of account numbers for each month in the year, but also give the user the choice to pick which months they want to see. I need to be able to see the amount of accounts that were closed between the beginning of the month of the start date and end of the month of the end date that they choose, or if the close date is null, but by each month.
If they choose just January, I want them to see the total of accounts for January 1st through January 31st, but if they pick January to December, I want them to see January 1st through December 31st, but I want the total per month.
I also want this to work for all years as well.

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS SMALLDATETIME

SET @StartDate = '01-01-2019'
SET @EndDate = '12-31-2019'

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(a.ACCOUNTNUMBER) AS [December]
FROM dbo.ACCOUNT A
WHERE ((a.CLOSEDATE >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @StartDate), 0)
            AND a.CLOSEDATE <= EOMONTH(@EndDate))
            OR a.CLOSEDATE IS NULL)
            AND a.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
```

This is my result now:

[image]

This is my desired result:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query for counting records per month](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20154434/2029983)

Comment: A SQL table can only returns a fixed set of columns.  It sounds like you want a variable number of columns, based on input parameters.  That requires dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, do you have any tips on Dynamic SQL? I'm still learning.

Comment: OR you can do a fancy CTE instead o dynamic sql. Just have null months be null

Comment: @DougCoats, Do you have any tips on CTEs?

Comment: @Lexirainbow I guess i could give tips and what not if you need them - though i woul dbe rehashing what you could get form any tutorial

Answer (score 1):

This should give the results you want but by rows not columns. I also had to make an assumption on what to use for date when closeddate is null. If you need more assistance or this isnt correct, we can work to solve it

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS SMALLDATETIME

SET @StartDate = '01-01-2019'
SET @EndDate = '12-31-2019'

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(a.ACCOUNTNUMBER) AS [Accounts]
, DATENAME(m, Month(ISNULL(ClosedDate, a.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day, - 1, getdate()), 112)))) Monthof
FROM dbo.ACCOUNT A
WHERE 
    (
        (
            a.CLOSEDATE >= @StartDate
            AND a.CLOSEDATE <= @EndDate
        )
        OR a.CLOSEDATE IS NULL
    )
    AND a.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day, - 1, getdate()), 112)
GROUP BY
    DATENAME(m, Month(ISNULL(ClosedDate, a.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day, - 1, getdate()), 112))))
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for the ISNULL(@EndDate, a.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day, - 1, getdate()), 112)) near the = sign. What would need to be "ClosedDate"?
I appreciate the help.

Comment: @lexirainbow change closeddate to closedate. my bad, typos

Comment: I'm still getting a syntax error. Am I able to put "a.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day, - 1, getdate())" in an ISNULL function?

Comment: the ", DATENAME(m, Month(ISNULL(a.CLOSEDATE, a.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day, - 1, getdate()), 112)))) Monthof" line
It says "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '='.
"

Comment: I think it might have to do that closedate is a date and that the other side of the isnull function is a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207437/discussion-between-doug-coats-and-lexirainbow).

Comment: sorry clicke don the link

Comment: I messaged you on the chat